# How to add aspx page as a view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can add a controller and a view and it creates a CSHTML file.  I want to however have my aspx page that has my form on it be in that same menu and use the bootstrap that the other pages are using... how do I do that? I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is what my menu looks like:

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Data", "About", "Home")</li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers")</li>       
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Customers", "Index", "addCustomer")</li>
```

I know how to add a new web form an it creates Text.aspx or whatever I name it but I want that page to show up in the menu and when clicked on to come up looking like all the other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little confused on **exactly** what you're looking to achieve, but here it goes:

Since `.aspx` files don't user Razor, and you can't tell it to use the `_Layout` page.. you are going to have to reference the bootstrap file manually in your `aspx` page like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In addition to doing that, you're going to have to add the necessary bootstrap class names (like `container`, `navbar-default`, etc) on all elements that would make that page look like the rest.. I assume you could just have the same layout as your `_Layout` page.

Then if you want to add a link to that `aspx` page.. then just drag and drop that form, from your solution explorer, to the page that you want a link for it.

As soon as you drop that form on the page you want link on, then it should look like something like this:

```
<a href="~/WebForm1.aspx">~/WebForm1.aspx</a>
```

So your menu would look like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Data", "About", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers")</li>       
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Customers", "Index", "addCustomer")</li>
<li><a href="~/WebForm1.aspx">~/WebForm1.aspx</a></li>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It sure does.... I was just looking for clarity if I could have my "form" page look like the other pages more or less which it looks like I can't... that sucks!  I don't mind the cshtml pages but like working with asp/c# for my forms.

Comment: @TimStrathman To be clear, this doesn't add the ASPX page as a view. It just creates a hyperlink to it.

Comment: Right @mason I knew that going into it I was just hoping to be able to make a form in asp/c# and have it look like the rest of the site but sounds like I can't.  Can make a good looking form in cshtml just can't get it to send data to SQL like I want to or can in c#